# Podman desktop always in initializing status

Tags: podman

I'm try to use podman desktop to replace the docker desktop. When I install this podman desktop and  open it, it always in initializing status. I don't know what's wrong with it. Anybody encountered the same problem?

[image]

I want to install and use the podman desktop and figure out what's wrong with it.

Answer (score -2):

Selecting "View/Force Reload" fixed it for me.

Comment: I tried "View/Force Reload", but it didn't work.

Comment: Hi @QingboYang - I am facing the same issue. You found the solution?

Comment: Not yet, I just use the command line now.